# Which Linux distribution is the preferred one for running a gwan server?

Tags: linux, distribution, g-wan

If I could choose from CentOS, Ubuntu, Debian, Gentoo or Fedora for running a G-wan server. Which one would you recommend as best?

Thanks.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ideal world, server distributions would provide a bare to the bone core - and let users add what they need.

But that's not what we are provided with.

So, to answer your question, there's a [dedicated G-WAN FAQ entry](http://gwan.ch/faq#bplatforms), or you can build your own Linux if you have the need, the time and the skills.